# How to fix: Vim completion list selecting completions from bottom of the list and moving upwards

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

Screenshot: [image]
Vimrc: http://pastebin.com/jijwTChi

As you can see from the screenshot, when the completion list opens it selects the word at the bottom of the list first and moves upwards.

How do I make the selection start from the top of the list - which almost all the time is the most relevant one.

Answer (score 3):

At which side of the list the autocompletion starts, depends on the shortcut you use:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> starts at the top of the list and moves down
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> starts at the bottom of the list and moves up

Check `:h i_CTRL-N` for more info

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I wrote? :-) In any case, one of them will accomplish van Mir Nazim wants.